# boundary( geometric realization of the standard n-simplex) is not equal to the geometric realization of the boundary(standard n-simplex) in general

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider $|\Delta^n|$ the geometric realization of the standard n-simplex. I know that the  $|\delta \Delta^n|=\delta|\Delta^n|$ isn't true in general, whereby $\delta \Delta^n$ is the boundary of the n-simplex. If i consider $\delta_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}|\Delta^n|$, the dimension of $\delta_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}|\Delta^n|$ is n but i want to embed the boundary of $|\Delta^n|$ in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, such that the equality $|\delta \Delta^n|=\delta|\Delta^n|$ will be true; maybe $\delta_{U}|\Delta^n|$ with $U=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\sum_{k=0}^nx_i=1\}$ with $dim_\mathbb{R}U=n$, is it possible? How does the set $\delta_{U}|\Delta^n|$look like? Is it the sphere $S^{n+1}$ or only homeomorphic? 
 I hope you understand my problem. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of dimension. If you embed the $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ or higher, the geometric boundary will actually be the whole simplex! (Think about what happens when you embed an interval in $\mathbb R^2$.) So you need to embed the $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ for the boundaries to behave like you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question, but I'll try to answer it:

$|\Delta^n | = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \sum x_i = 1 \}$

We call $(1,0,0....)$ the first vertex, $(0,1,0....)$ the second, etc. By the $i$th face, I will mean the face opposite to the $i$th vertex.

The $i$th face of the standard $n$-simplex, $d_i |\Delta^n| = \{x \in |\Delta^n| : x_i = 0 \}$.

The boundary $\partial |\Delta^n|$ is the union of all the faces $0 \leq i \leq n$.

Each face is a copy of $|\Delta^{n-1}|$. For example the map

$(x_1, x_2) \to (x_1,0,x_2)$

gives a homeomorphism $|\Delta^{1}| \to d_1|\Delta^{2}|$.

Nothing simplicial will "look like" a sphere. The sphere is "smooth" and simplicial things have edges and corners (piecewise linear). But for the purposes of topology,  $\partial|\Delta^{n+1}|$ and $S^n$ are the same, ie. homeomorphic.

Comment: yes, i was confused. Do you know what the homeomorphism between $\partial_U|\Delta^n|$ and $S^n$ is explicitly? But i asked it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008644/homeomorphism-between-a-boundary-and-a-sphere too. I think it has to be $S^{n-1}$n instead of $S^n$. Sorry it is difficult for me to explain it on english what my question is, because me english isn't good:(. I did my best. But your answer is helpful for me. Regards I

Comment: I don't know what $\partial_U | \Delta^n |$ is, and it seems that people were already trying to explain to you in the previous answer you link that you should write $\partial | \Delta^n |$ instead.

Comment: As for an explicit homeomorphism between $S^n$ and $\partial|\Delta^{n+1}|$, I've never seen one written down, and I don't know how to do it. You can try working it out, but it won't help you get better at topology...